# Cumulative Total for Count -SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
Select 
    DATEPART(m,CREDAT_0) as Month, 
    COUNT(CREDAT_0) as count,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as totalcount 
from 
    x3v6.CICPROD.ITMFACILIT
group by
    DATEPART(m,CREDAT_0)
order by 
    Month asc
```

Which returns the result set:

```
Month count totalcount
    1   56  2713
    2   12  2713
    3   39  2713
    4   36  2713
    5   54  2713
    6   32  2713
    7   27  2713
    8   12  2713
    9   32  2713
    10  20722713
    11  187 2713
    12  154 2713
```

But I want to see a cumulative total of products created by month for the year. So a column like this:

```
Month count totalcount cumtotal
    1   56  2713           56
    2   12  2713           68
    3   39  2713           107
    4   36  2713           etc..
    5   54  2713
    6   32  2713
    7   27  2713
    8   12  2713
    9   32  2713
    10  20722713
    11  187 2713
    12  154 2713           2713
```

How would I accomplish this? (if a way exists). I am using T-SQL in SQL Server 2012.

Thank you

Comment: You use a windowing function.

Answer (score 4):

For the last column

```
...
, COUNT(*) OVER (Order by CREDAT_0) as cumcount 
...
```

Comment: Thanks I was trying to use PARTITION by , but didn't realize it wasn't required. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @MikeMirabelli Only if  you wanted to reset the count i,e, Year over Year

Answer (score 0):

you can write query like below:

```
sum([count]) over(order by CREDAT_0) as CumulativeCount
```